# How did a special-character tag get into the system?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Observe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313854/just-a-test-to-screw-with-the-tags-closed) (which will be shortly deleted but is being kept for observation).

It has a tag of [`[#]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%23). The sidebar says `[#] x 2`, but clicking on it [doesn't work too well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%23).

So now I'm left to wonder if there is, in fact, another `#` question. But should this even be allowed in the first place? I can't think of any legitimate tags that don't include at least one letter or number (404 being an example of a legitimate tag with no letters).

Tagging this question as `#`, `.`, `&`, and `-`.

**Edit:** Those tags were stripped out. Which now turns this into a question of, how did that get there?

Comment: Sorry for all of the edits...

Comment: the "clicking on it doesn't work too well" part is a dupe, I just haven't found the original yet

Comment: @balpha I think I deleted the original dupe of this because I thought it was crazy.. looks like I was the crazy one

Comment: Related: [How did the \[html+php\] tag come to exist and how can we make it die?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164050/how-did-the-htmlphp-tag-come-to-exist-and-how-can-we-make-it-die)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my bad -- bug in the sanitization routine. There is a new unrolled loop one now.

The rules for tag strings are somewhat complex:

- max of 35 chars
- valid tag chars are `a-z 0-9 # + - .`
- we automatically convert `_` to `-` wherever we see it
- tags can't *start* with `-` or `#`
- tags can't *end* with `-` or `.`
- other characters cannot appear after a `+`
- wildcard, if allowed, is `*` (this is for client side use only; server wildcard is `~`)

Comment: `+` behaves strangely: [The + character in tag names breaks links.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102957/155238)

Answer (score 11):

> I can't think of any legitimate tags that don't include at least one letter or number (404 being an example of a legitimate tag with no letters).

I disagree.

It would be awesome to be able to tag things like operators consisting only of symbols `?:` `>>>=` `>@>` and so on. Especially as Google and most other search engines don't seem to be able to index these tokens. A lot of questions about these operators get repeated over and over, often with a line "I've tried Googling but couldn't find anything".

This feature would actually make me want to use SO's search.

Comment: Good point ....

Comment: You make a good point but by the way the system is currently designed, this is a bug

Comment: `#!` might be even more popular than those.

Comment: ternary operator!

Comment: @Shog9, you should know better!  ___ [Conditional operator.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25) ___

Comment: @Popular: [if we knew what it was called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-operator%20or%20ternary-operator), we wouldn't need symbols in tags!

Comment: @Shog9, right, but I'm sure you __do__ know.  And I apologize for the formatting of the last comment, I couldn't get Markdown to do what I wanted.  Took five or so edits just to get it to where it is.

Comment: What's wrong with the last comment? @Pop
Back on-topic (sorta), [there was a bit of discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49012/how-could-we-fix-the-ternary-operator-problem) about this a while back...

Comment: @Shog9, er, it was supposed to just be a quick amusing comment.  I know that newbies do often helplessly ask about it; I would have probably done so myself, if Stack Overflow had existed when I was learning Java.  I was working off of the point that you are not such a newbie, but you yelled out "ternary operator" and not "conditional operator" anyways.

Comment: @Popular: no worries, I laughed.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to add the [#] tag back in by encasing it in double quotes - "#".  If you edit this question the quotes are not present in the tags field, however the hash / pound sign is still there.

I also tried to add the other special characters you mention.  With all 4 only the dot (.) tag remained.  This is what I entered for tags:

```
bug "#" "." "&" "-"
```

Comment: thanks for the repro, this helped