# The + character in tag names breaks links.

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-wiki

Over at Math.SE we decided to merge two tags into one and give it a combined name. After reading up [on the character number limit and the allowed characters in tag names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58142/how-did-a-special-character-tag-get-into-the-system/58870#58870), we decided to rename our new tag `(examples+counterexamples)`, since it is a tag about, well, examples *and* counterexamples.

Great, now I go to the [Math.SE tags page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags) and type in the search box "examples" and I see our spanking new tag.

Now I think: hey, let me edit the tag wiki for it, and see what questions are now tagged under it! So I [clicked the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples+counterexamples)... and it doesn't take me where I want it to. How am I suppose to access the tag wiki then?

Comment: BTW: it looks like the + character is interfering with how the system parse a request to see questions simultaneously using two tags. If this *is* the intended behaviour, can someone from the SE team rename that tag to `(examples-counterexamples)`?

Comment: It's pretty clearly intended, goint to `tags/homework+calculus` shows questions tagged both `homework` and `calculus` for example.  Escaping the `+` to `%2B` doesn't work either, so your proposed change for the tag is a good idea; they should also auto-convert `+` to `-` when a tag is created, or something.

Comment: It is interesting that this does not seem to affect trailing `+` as in the `c++` tag, or I'm sure we'd have heard about this long ago.

Comment: There's all sorts of stupid breakages related to `c++`, actually, now that I went and looked for them. Try the following links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++0x+c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+++c++0x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+++c%23

Comment: But on stackoverflow apparently one can use a space to concatenate tag names: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++ c%23` which is how the links from "related tags" are created when you access the page for questions tagged as (c#) or (c++), which would then prevent the breakage. So perhaps a certain workaround is hardcoded for SO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop doing that!  I fixed it in the database to `[examples-counterexamples]` (search and such will index in the next 15 minutes).

Obviously there's a gap in the merge screen that allow this through, we'll get around to fixing this rare case.

Comment: So is `+` actually a disallowed character? (If so maybe Jeff should edit his answer in that linked question.)

Comment: @Willie - In the middle of a tag, yes...this isn't really supported.  I updated the post in question to eliminate the confusion over the rules here.

Comment: Is there an error message presented upon attempting to use such invalid characters in a tag name? If not, have you considered adding such a thing? Most people doing this probably haven't read [Jeff's official rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58142/how-did-a-special-character-tag-get-into-the-system/58870#58870).

Comment: @Cody - this can *only* happen via the moderator merge screens as far as we're aware...you can't do it through normal user UI means.  We will add a message to the mod screens through, just very busy at the moment, you'll see why soon :)