# Preview Breaks with Invalid Tag Name [tag:+]

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, javascript, markdown-preview

In the formatted preview for Questions & Answers, typing a tag link with an invalid tag name "crashes" the preview. As soon as you type the following the preview stops updating and an error can be observed in the Javascript console.

```
[tag:+]
```

Observed in Safari 7 and Chrome 31.

[The + character in tag names breaks links.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102957/the-character-in-tag-names-breaks-links) seems related to the business rule of not allowing certain characters in tags, but it sounds like a different bug.

Comment: This problem also occurs with `[tag:.]` (period), and I'm presuming other characters as well. Escaping the braces/colon does not stop the problem from occurring. I just ran into this issue as well and was directed here.

Comment: This also breaks with `[tag:and]`.

Comment: Also breaks with `[tag:or]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build. The preview and rendered version still aren't 100% consistent in some broken cases. I'll look at that at some point, but I'm not worried about it too much.

At least they don't crash the editor anymore.

Comment: Just to double-check, since you closed [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230305/) as a dupe of this one - will my editing toolbar reappear when the next build rolls out?

Comment: Ah, the next build just rolled out, and I do indeed have my editing toolbars back. Thanks!