# Search in Tags tab using non alphanumeric characters

Tags: feature-request, tags

If you go to [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) tab on StackOverflow and type into the *Type to find tags* edit e.g. <kbd>#</kbd> char, you would expect to get filtered all tags containing <kbd>#</kbd> char in their name. This seems to be ignored as well as the other non alphanumeric chars typed into this edit.

---

[image: screenshot of the problem]

---

Would be possible to add this *feature* ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [tag naming rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58870/166025):

- max of 25 chars
- valid tag chars are a-z 0-9 # + - .
- we automatically convert _ to - wherever we see it
- tags can't start with - or #
- tags can't end with - or .
- "+" is only valid at the end of a tag

Users can search for *c#* or *c+* but since tag name cannot start with *#* and *+*, so searching for just a *#* in tags tab will not be useful.