# A user with one rep created a bogus new tag, [android+sqlite+insert]

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

See earlier bug for description of symptoms and background: [How did the [html+php] tag come to exist and how can we make it die?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164050/135887).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15376846/168868) created the tag `android+sqlite+insert`.  <s>Please *do not* edit the question just yet, lest you destroy evidence</s>.  Yes, it needs improvement and could possibly need closing as Too Localized, but let's not worry about that right now.

You will note that the user has one rep.  *One* rep.

How did this user without the ability to create tags not just create a tag, but create a *bogus* tag?

Comment: here's the evidence just in case: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XnlGK.png

Comment: While clicking on edit link, it shows three different tags, strange !!!

Comment: Is there, perhaps, a way to start a new question by giving querystring parameters to a page that in some way includes tags? Spaces in querystrings are, famously, represented by plusses. Also, clicking on the tag itself doesn't lead to a tag-wiki - but a search with all three tags included.

Comment: this means the bug is not fixed

Comment: what you say is true; that did indeed happen, and the tag is credited to the 1-rep user; investigating; edit: ah, I see...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for reporting; it looks like we had some tag-handling code that processes both url forms (where `+` might be used interchangeably with `%20` as a separator) and "text" forms (where we only expect space as a separator) - so some wrong code paths were taken when *validating* the tags. This will be fixed in the next build.

Basically, [android](/questions/tagged/android), [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) and [insert](/questions/tagged/insert) already existed, and it got a bit confused.