# How can I browse through tags that contain the character "+"?

Tags: support, tags, search

I noticed that Stack Overflow en español has a tag named `[php+codeigniter+mysql+jquery]`:

> [image]

You can browse in https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags.

However, if I click on the tag it sends me to https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%2bcodeigniter%2bmysql%2bjquery. That is, a page containing the questions with all the tags: `[php] + [codeigniter] + [mysql] + [jquery]`.

How can I browse that specific tag? I tried with `[php\+codeigniter\+mysql\+jquery]` but it was rewritten as `[php] [codeigniter] [mysql] [jquery]` in the results page.

Comment: I think this is more of a bug then a support question.

Comment: I think it is easier if you have that tag renamed to replace the + with a -

Comment: @rene I am trying to just get rid of the tag, only that I cannot find the way to get the question that has the tag.

Comment: @rene And then you burninate it to the ground, right?

Comment: @yivi yes, probably somebody mistyped. I want to remove the tag by converting it into normal [php] [codeigniter] bla bla, but I cannot find a way to get into the question using it

Comment: @yivi it is PHP, it is a fine tag ...

Comment: @rene Only problem is, you'd end up with tags like [c--].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's this question: [Rellenar tabla en PHP utilizando codeigniter y recogiendo datos desde daterangepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345210/rellenar-tabla-en-php-utilizando-codeigniter-y-recogiendo-datos-desde-daterangep). I'm wondering how that 1 rep user was able to create a new tag... or did it exist on another question back then?

I found it through the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), with [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=php%2Bcodeigniter%2Bmysql%2Bjquery&filter=default&site=es.stackoverflow&run=true) to the 'search' method.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks! I just edited it. The funny thing is that clicking on "edit" has already split the four-items-tag into individual ones. I wonder how this tag could be created.

Comment: And thanks for showing what is the way to find such questions: by using the API

Comment: As that question is more then a week old SEDE will work as well: https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1294722?weirdtag=php%2B%25

Comment: To [answer the part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164079/311398) where you were wondering how the tag was created.