# Get rid of special characters when searching for a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, ignored-tags, tag-watching

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58870/381660), there is a limited number of valid characters for a tag. If we don't allow special characters in a tag name in the first place, shouldn't we get rid of special characters (such as `~`, `` ` ``, `&`, `^`, `%`, `$`, and others) from even showing up as we are searching for tags (watching/ignoring a tag as well)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Get rid in what sense? Prevent showing up where?