# New Stacks editor incorrectly renders tag markup with disallowed characters as valid tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, stacks-editor, commonmark

When I typed `[tag:*-faq]` in the new stacks editor, it rendered as a tag (like [asterisk-faq](/questions/tagged/asterisk-faq)), but then when I posted my answer, the unrendered Markdown was displayed.

Further, the Markdown following the asterisk was also italic.

**Screenshot showing Stacks editor Markdown:**
[image: Screenshot showing Stacks editor Markdown]

**Screenshot showing Stacks editor rendered Markdown:**
[image: Screenshot showing Stacks editor rendered Markdown]

**Screenshot showing how Markdown was rendered on Meta SO:**
[image: Screenshot showing how Markdown was rendered on Meta SO]

Comment: I think the hyphen is the only not latin char permitted in tags, closest post with rules I could find was [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135929). The [FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) doesn't seem to have a link for the tag naming rules.

Comment: I'd say you're probably correct. It makes sense to me that markdown would disallow asterisks in tag names. The trouble, for me anyway, was just the inconsistency. It resulted in me posting an incorrectly formatted answer.

Comment: I think what's happening is that the post gets sanitized after being submitted to not render as a tag because it contains an illegal character (I didn't check the CommonMark specification and I'm supposing it's an SE rule). If that's the case it seems that the Stack editor isn't aware of that specific post rule and just renders the tag as such in preview regardless of the characters the tags contains.

Comment: The bug regarding "the Markdown following the asterisk was also italic" has been reported before: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360038/513150. See also: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21

Comment: @bad_coder I don't recall the list of characters permitted in tags, but, at a minimum, the "+` character is also permitted, as is shown for the [tag:c++-faq] tag in the screenshots in this question. Latin characters. IIRC, one criteria is that the tag must *begin* with a Latin character.

Comment: I just tested `[tag:\*-faq]` using the CommonMark escape character and it also doesn't work in the post and breaks the tag in preview.

Comment: Here's the full list of rules for tag names, pretty sure this is still current: [Tag Name Rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58870)

Answer (score 5):

I just checked and this is the way that the current editor (not the Stacks Editor) works in terms of rendering something like `[tag:*-faq]` in the preview and in the text rendered on the server. An asterisk is not a legal character in a tag name (it can be used in favorite/ignore lists, but not in saved tag names, as far as I can tell), so it is correct to not render this as a tag.

The issue, if any, is that the Stacks Editor should *not* be rendering this as a tag, as it is not a legal tag. This has been fixed, and should no longer be happening.

> if there's asterisk
> in a tag name; no render
> like all other tags

Comment: Cheers Yaakov! Happy to see this one marked `[tag:status-completed]` :)